Setting up denols to work along with tsls in kickstart neovim
I want to set up language server for my JS/TS project with Deno. I am using modular_kickstart which is a fork of kickstart neovim. I have put my config for deno in my lspconfig.nvim plugin file like so:
-- LSP Plugins
return {
  {
    -- `lazydev` configures Lua LSP for your Neovim config, runtime and plugins
    -- used for completion, annotations and signatures of Neovim apis
    'folke/lazydev.nvim',
    ft = 'lua',
    opts = {
      library = {
        -- Load luvit types when the `vim.uv` word is found
        { path = 'luvit-meta/library', words = { 'vim%.uv' } },
      },
    },
  },
  { 'Bilal2453/luvit-meta', lazy = true },
  {
    -- Main LSP Configuration
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {
      -- Automatically install LSPs and related tools to stdpath for Neovim
      { 'williamboman/mason.nvim', config = true }, -- NOTE: Must be loaded before dependants
      'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
      'WhoIsSethDaniel/mason-tool-installer.nvim',

      -- Useful status updates for LSP.
      -- NOTE: `opts = {}` is the same as calling `require('fidget').setup({})`
      { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim', opts = {} },

      -- Allows extra capabilities provided by nvim-cmp
      'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp',
    },
    config = function()
      -- Brief aside: **What is LSP?**
      --
      -- LSP is an initialism you've probably heard, but might not understand what it is.
      --
      -- LSP stands for Language Server Protocol. It's a protocol that helps editors
      -- and language tooling communicate in a standardized fashion.
      --
      -- In general, you have a "server" which is some tool built to understand a particular
      -- language (such as `gopls`, `lua_ls`, `rust_analyzer`, etc.). These Language Servers
      -- (sometimes called LSP servers, but that's kind of like ATM Machine) are standalone
      -- processes that communicate with some "client" - in this case, Neovim!
      --
      -- LSP provides Neovim with features like:
      --  - Go to definition
      --  - Find references
      --  - Autocompletion
      --  - Symbol Search
      --  - and more!
      --
      -- Thus, Language Servers are external tools that must be installed separately from
      -- Neovim. This is where `mason` and related plugins come into play.
      --
      -- If you're wondering about lsp vs treesitter, you can check out the wonderfully
      -- and elegantly composed help section, `:help lsp-vs-treesitter`

      --  This function gets run when an LSP attaches to a particular buffer.
      --    That is to say, every time a new file is opened that is associated with
      --    an lsp (for example, opening `main.rs` is associated with `rust_analyzer`) this
      --    function will be executed to configure the current buffer
      vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
        group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('kickstart-lsp-attach', { clear = true }),
        callback = function(event)
          -- NOTE: Remember that Lua is a real programming language, and as such it is possible
          -- to define small helper and utility functions so you don't have to repeat yourself.
          --
          -- In this case, we create a function that lets us more easily define mappings specific
          -- for LSP related items. It sets the mode, buffer and description for us each time.
          local map = function(keys, func, desc, mode)
            mode = mode or 'n'
            vim.keymap.set(mode, keys, func, { buffer = event.buf, desc = 'LSP: ' .. desc })
          end

          -- Jump to the definition of the word under your cursor.
          --  This is where a variable was first declared, or where a function is defined, etc.
          --  To jump back, press <C-t>.
          map('gd', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_definitions, '[G]oto [D]efinition')

          -- Find references for the word under your cursor.
          map('gr', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, '[G]oto [R]eferences')

          -- Jump to the implementation of the word under your cursor.
          --  Useful when your language has ways of declaring types without an actual implementation.
          map('gI', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_implementations, '[G]oto [I]mplementation')

          -- Jump to the type of the word under your cursor.
          --  Useful when you're not sure what type a variable is and you want to see
          --  the definition of its *type*, not where it was *defined*.
          map('<leader>D', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_type_definitions, 'Type [D]efinition')

          -- Fuzzy find all the symbols in your current document.
          --  Symbols are things like variables, functions, types, etc.
          map('<leader>ds', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_document_symbols, '[D]ocument [S]ymbols')

          -- Fuzzy find all the symbols in your current workspace.
          --  Similar to document symbols, except searches over your entire project.
          map('<leader>ws', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbols, '[W]orkspace [S]ymbols')

          -- Rename the variable under your cursor.
          --  Most Language Servers support renaming across files, etc.
          map('<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, '[R]e[n]ame')

          -- Execute a code action, usually your cursor needs to be on top of an error
          -- or a suggestion from your LSP for this to activate.
          map('<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, '[C]ode [A]ction', { 'n', 'x' })

          -- WARN: This is not Goto Definition, this is Goto Declaration.
          --  For example, in C this would take you to the header.
          map('gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, '[G]oto [D]eclaration')

          -- The following two autocommands are used to highlight references of the
          -- word under your cursor when your cursor rests there for a little while.
          --    See `:help CursorHold` for information about when this is executed
          --
          -- When you move your cursor, the highlights will be cleared (the second autocommand).
          local client = vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(event.data.client_id)
          if client and client.supports_method(vim.lsp.protocol.Methods.textDocument_documentHighlight) then
            local highlight_augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('kickstart-lsp-highlight', { clear = false })
            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'CursorHold', 'CursorHoldI' }, {
              buffer = event.buf,
              group = highlight_augroup,
              callback = vim.lsp.buf.document_highlight,
            })

            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'CursorMoved', 'CursorMovedI' }, {
              buffer = event.buf,
              group = highlight_augroup,
              callback = vim.lsp.buf.clear_references,
            })

            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspDetach', {
              group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('kickstart-lsp-detach', { clear = true }),
              callback = function(event2)
                vim.lsp.buf.clear_references()
                vim.api.nvim_clear_autocmds { group = 'kickstart-lsp-highlight', buffer = event2.buf }
              end,
            })
          end

          -- The following code creates a keymap to toggle inlay hints in your
          -- code, if the language server you are using supports them
          --
          -- This may be unwanted, since they displace some of your code
          if client and client.supports_method(vim.lsp.protocol.Methods.textDocument_inlayHint) then
            map('<leader>th', function()
              vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(not vim.lsp.inlay_hint.is_enabled { bufnr = event.buf })
            end, '[T]oggle Inlay [H]ints')
          end
        end,
      })

      -- Change diagnostic symbols in the sign column (gutter)
      -- if vim.g.have_nerd_font then
      --   local signs = { Error = '', Warn = '', Hint = '', Info = '' }
      --   for type, icon in pairs(signs) do
      --     local hl = 'DiagnosticSign' .. type
      --     vim.fn.sign_define(hl, { text = icon, texthl = hl, numhl = hl })
      --   end
      -- end

      -- LSP servers and clients are able to communicate to each other what features they support.
      --  By default, Neovim doesn't support everything that is in the LSP specification.
      --  When you add nvim-cmp, luasnip, etc. Neovim now has *more* capabilities.
      --  So, we create new capabilities with nvim cmp, and then broadcast that to the servers.
      local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
      capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', capabilities, require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities())

      -- Enable the following language servers
      --  Feel free to add/remove any LSPs that you want here. They will automatically be installed.
      --
      --  Add any additional override configuration in the following tables. Available keys are:
      --  - cmd (table): Override the default command used to start the server
      --  - filetypes (table): Override the default list of associated filetypes for the server
      --  - capabilities (table): Override fields in capabilities. Can be used to disable certain LSP features.
      --  - settings (table): Override the default settings passed when initializing the server.
      --        For example, to see the options for `lua_ls`, you could go to: https://luals.github.io/wiki/settings/
      local servers = {
        -- clangd = {},
        -- gopls = {},
        -- pyright = {},
        -- rust_analyzer = {},
        -- ... etc. See `:help lspconfig-all` for a list of all the pre-configured LSPs
        --
        -- Some languages (like typescript) have entire language plugins that can be useful:
        --    https://github.com/pmizio/typescript-tools.nvim
        --
        -- But for many setups, the LSP (`ts_ls`) will work just fine
        -- ts_ls = {},
        --

        lua_ls = {
          -- cmd = {...},
          -- filetypes = { ...},
          -- capabilities = {},
          settings = {
            Lua = {
              completion = {
                callSnippet = 'Replace',
              },
              -- You can toggle below to ignore Lua_LS's noisy `missing-fields` warnings
              -- diagnostics = { disable = { 'missing-fields' } },
            },
          },
        },
      }

      -- Ensure the servers and tools above are installed
      --  To check the current status of installed tools and/or manually install
      --  other tools, you can run
      --    :Mason
      --
      --  You can press `g?` for help in this menu.
      require('mason').setup()

      -- You can add other tools here that you want Mason to install
      -- for you, so that they are available from within Neovim.
      local ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers or {})
      vim.list_extend(ensure_installed, {
        'stylua', -- Used to format Lua code
      })
      require('mason-tool-installer').setup { ensure_installed = ensure_installed }

      require('mason-lspconfig').setup {
        handlers = {
          function(server_name)
            local server = servers[server_name] or {}
            -- This handles overriding only values explicitly passed
            -- by the server configuration above. Useful when disabling
            -- certain features of an LSP (for example, turning off formatting for ts_ls)
            server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
            require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
          end,
        },
      }
    end,
  },
}
-- vim: ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 et

I have followed the suggestion on the official deno docs for setup for neovim. It say to put this in my lspconfig file.
local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')
nvim_lsp.denols.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  root_dir = nvim_lsp.util.root_pattern("deno.json", "deno.jsonc"),
}

nvim_lsp.ts_ls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  root_dir = nvim_lsp.util.root_pattern("package.json"),
  single_file_support = false
}

However, I am facing conflict with my ts_ls and denols occupying the same buffer. I am unaware with the lazy.nvim lua configuration used by the modular_kickstart as well as kickstart nvim.

Since you are using Mason LSP Config and Kickstart you have to place your config in the servers table:
    local servers = {
        lua_ls = {
            settings = {
                Lua = {
                    completion = {
                        callSnippet = "Replace",
                    },
                    hint = {
                        enable = true,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        ts_ls = {
            root_dir = require("lspconfig").util.root_pattern({ "package.json", "tsconfig.json" }),
            single_file_support = false,
            settings = {},
        },
        denols = {
            root_dir = require("lspconfig").util.root_pattern({"deno.json", "deno.jsonc"}),
            single_file_support = false,
            settings = {},
        },
    }

The suggested config from Deno website only works if you are not using Mason LSP Config.
You don't need to pass on_attach since Kickstart already sets an autocommand on 'LspAttach'

Thanks a lot. It really solved my problem.

I have tested few things by building a simple web app with oak and react. I am seeing some error messages like:
Cannot find module '@oak/oak' or its corresponding type declarations. [2307]
If I am importing the package import {} from "../.";
The this run perfectly if I try to run the app but that annoying error is not going away.
I trying the test my deno setup by making this project
https://docs.deno.com/examples/create_react_tutorial/

@Mr.Unforgettable That is a ts_ls warning. As you can see in the config ts_ls will start when a package.json or tsconfig.json files exists in the current working directory and denols will start when a deno.json file exists, so both servers are running in the same project. My suggestion is you can turn off ts_ls when you are working in those deno.json and package.json/tsconfig.json mixed projects and only keep denols running. You can also write a function or autocommand in your nvim config so that happens automatically when you open that kind of project.
